# Using named pages in @media print css

Tags: html, css, printing, media

I have trouble with this [Using named pages](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-page-20130314/#page).

```
@page mypage{
    margin:0; 
}
div.mypage{
    page:mypage;
}

<div class="mypage">Some content</div>
```

But maybe real question is: does anyone browser support this rules?

Comment: A good article was just published on print styling, and I believe this was one of the things mentioned drublic.de/blog/printing-the-web/

Comment: The article has been moved to archive:
https://drublic.de/archive/printing-the-web/

Here's is another article that includes a nice example, I recommend looking at the source code to really get a feel for what's going on, the descriptions didn't get into enough detail for me:
http://alistapart.com/article/boom

Answer (score 2):

@page rule basic support (css2.1) is well supported. the page type selector that you are using in your example is css3 (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-page/#using-named-pages)...as for browser support, your guess is as good as mine. its not shown on caniuse.com, nor in mdn.

Comment: Does it works?I am unable to get results of named pages. Tho psuedo-selectors are working

Comment: i'm not sure in your case, its not clear what your case is.

Comment: I am using named pages, from the examples of w3 drafts, but when I am printing the example, it is not working at all.

Comment: without seeing your code, i have no clue. you may want to ask this as a question.

Comment: I cannot ask a question. Expected PDF; https://gitlab.pagedmedia.org/tools/pagedjs-cli/uploads/931c5a87747110e74d816e19dbd08fe5/test.pdf